# how can ı solve this problem ?print the values entered with the inputbox to the textbox, then transfer the values from the textbox to an array

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim girilensayı As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        girilensayı = InputBox("bir sayı gir")

        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            TextBox1.Text = girilensayı
        Else
            TextBox1.Text += " " & girilensayı
        End If
```

I need to transfer in textbox values to the array

Comment: Hint: String class has a method called Split that creates an array from your input and with a given separator between words. Also InputBox returns a string not a double

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code files

Comment: how can I get that values from textbox ?

how to use this splint method ?
could you give me an example ?

Comment: "Option Strict On " what does it work ?

Comment: @Kadir Option Strict On means that any and all variables used must be defined first before using them (defined with Dim, Shared, Private, Public etc)

Comment: finally,how to use split method or function. and does it work for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

```
Dim numberofValues As Integer
Dim Inputtext As String
Dim textArray(numberofValues) As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Inputtext = InputBox("Enter a Number")

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = Inputtext
        textArray(numberofValues) = Inputtext
        numberofValues += 1
    Else
        ReDim Preserve textArray(numberofValues)
        TextBox1.Text += " " & Inputtext
        textArray(numberofValues) = Inputtext
        numberofValues = numberofValues + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

The Code above will add all the values added to the text box to a array by increasing the size of the array through ReDim Preserve. I have tested the code and it is working. Instead of transferring them from the textbox they are added to the array as values are added to the textbox. Your Form will require a button and textbox with the correct names.

Comment: WHAT! Why in the world would you post an answer with Option Strict Off? Option Strict should always be On! Actually, there are very rare occasions where it is turned off.

Comment: @Mary I have edited the code, answered the question very late at night so I wasn't paying much attention. Thank you for the Correction though.

Comment: I know what you mean. I have posted some dizzy code at 3AM. :-) I will delete may comment in a bit.

Comment: @Mary I am a new Programmer and as you have a good rep I have a question, is this solution efficient or is there another more efficient method to it.

Comment: Move the ReDim Preserve to above the `TextBox1.Text = Inputtext`. Delete the If line and the rest of the Else and the End If. Change `TextBox1.Text = Inputtext` to `TextBox1.Text &= Inputtext` Although += will work in VB the & is the VB string concatenation operator. The extra ReDim won't hurt anything the first time through. As with any user input if you want a real number use .TryParse to verify. I avoided ReDim in my answer by using a List(Of T)

Comment: BTW, I think the way you did the ReDim  was very clever.

Comment: @Mary Thank you for the help and compliment.

Comment: @KadirÇolak No Problem

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```
'I am using a List because we don't know how
    'many elements we will have. This avoids a
    'series of ReDim Preserve in your code.
    Private lstDouble As New List(Of Double)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'InputBox returns a string so girilensayı is a string
        Dim girilensayı = InputBox("bir sayı gir")
        Dim myNumber As Double
        'TryParse will return True or False and fill in myNumber
        If Double.TryParse(girilensayı, myNumber) Then
            'I used the .ToString method so I could use a 
            'format string. "N2" will display your number
            'to 2 decimal places.
            TextBox1.Text &= myNumber.ToString("N2") & ", "
            'Add the number to the list
            lstDouble.Add(myNumber)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'If you need an array later you can lstDouble.ToArray
        Dim arrDouble() As Double = lstDouble.ToArray()
    End Sub
```

Comment: OP wants to enter multiple values in the inputbox and get an array from those values.

Comment: @preciousbetine Yes, but my understanding was that there would be only one entry at a time. There would be no way to control how a user would enter several numbers at a once.